# Explanation for a transformation step besides arrow in align environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, align, draw

When I transform math equations I like to add some explanation for every (major) step, such that one can readily see what I have done. Sometimes it's not obvious and it usually doesn't hurt to explain. Now the way I like to do this is to draw an arrow from one equal sign to the next below, which is aligned with the previous one. This is how this looks like right now:
[image: how it looks like now]
I attach the code I used to generate this below. That kind of works, but what I want to achieve is something more like this:
[image: how it should look like]

My goals are:

- draw an arrow from one equal sign to the next
- be able to add a description (math and/or text, possibly multiline, maybe different font or color) next to it
- simple use, for example as a command with one argument (as I have it right now)
- be able to use it in single and two column documents
- have a clean and reliable solution without artifacts
- the possibility to add pictures to a explanation would be a big bonus!

So my question is: How do I achieve this?? Thanks for your help!

Here's my code so far. I actually use it as a package, but chose to put it as a MWE here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{zref-abspos}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\remainder}
\newcounter{schritte}
\setcounter{schritte}{0}

\newcommand\setremainder{
    \setlength{\remainder}{\linewidth}%
    \addtolength{\remainder}{\oddsidemargin}%
    \addtolength{\remainder}{1 in}%
    \addtolength{\remainder}{\hoffset}%
    \addtolength{\remainder}{-\zposx{ende\theschritte} sp}%
}

\newcommand\setremainderstart{%
    \zsaveposx{ende\theschritte}%
}%

\newcommand{\schritttext}[1]{\stepcounter{schritte}\setremainder\left\downarrow\vphantom{\begin{varwidth}[c]{\remainder}%
    \vspace*{0pt}{\small {#1}}\end{varwidth}}\right. & \,%
    \setremainderstart\setremainder\begin{varwidth}[c]{\remainder}\vspace*{0pt}{\small {#1}}\end{varwidth} \nonumber\\}%

\newcommand{\schritt}[1]{\schritttext{\ensuremath{{#1}}}}

\makeatother


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f(x)=&x^2-3x+2\\
    \schritttext{Insert a "zero" }
        =& \hphantom{{}-{}}x^2-2x\frac{3}{2} + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\nonumber\\
         &- \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 +2\\
    \schritttext{use $a^2-2 ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$ (binomial formula)\\ also:  $2-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2= 2- \frac{9}{4}=\frac{8-9}{4}=-\frac{1}{4}$}
    =&\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt of an answer that uses the absolute positioning system of Ti*k*Z instead of `zref`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{schritte}
\setcounter{schritte}{0}

\newcommand{\schritttext}[1]{\stepcounter{schritte}%\setremainder\left\downarrow\vphantom{\begin{varwidth}[c]{\remainder}%
    %\vspace*{0pt}{\small {#1}}\end{varwidth}}\right. 
    & \hphantom{{}={}}\,\tikzmark{x\theschritte}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p1=($(current page text area.east)-(pic cs:x\theschritte)$)
    in \pgfextra{\xdef\remainder{\x1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{varwidth}[c]{\remainder}\vspace*{0pt}{\small {#1}}\end{varwidth} \nonumber\\}%
\newcommand{\schritt}[1]{\schritttext{\ensuremath{{#1}}}}

\makeatother


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f(x)&\tikzmarknode{eq\theschritte}{=}x^2-3x+2\\
    \schritttext{Insert a "zero" }
        &\tikzmarknode{eq\theschritte}{=} \hphantom{{}-{}}x^2-2x\frac{3}{2} + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\nonumber\\
         &\hphantom{{}=-{}}- \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 +2\\
    \schritttext{use $a^2-2 ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$ (binomial formula)\\ also:  $2-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2= 2- \frac{9}{4}=\frac{8-9}{4}=-\frac{1}{4}$}
    &\tikzmarknode{eq\theschritte}{=}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X-1)}] in {1,...,\theschritte}
    \draw[-latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=1pt] (eq\Y) -- (eq\X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output looks IMO reasonable. You could merge the drawing of the arrows into the definition of `\schritttext` if you are willing to load `atbegshi` (the lower `\tikzmarknode` is only set after the command `\schritttext` has been executed). Yet I have to admit that there are warnings generated by that proposal: `Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input line 34.`, and I am unable to interpret those, and thus cannot get rid of them.

On the bright site, this answer allows you to illustrate the Schritte with footprints. ;-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.footprints}


\newcounter{schritte}
\setcounter{schritte}{0}

\newcommand{\schritttext}[1]{\stepcounter{schritte}%\setremainder\left\downarrow\vphantom{\begin{varwidth}[c]{\remainder}%
    %\vspace*{0pt}{\small {#1}}\end{varwidth}}\right. 
    & \hphantom{{}={}}\,\tikzmark{x\theschritte}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p1=($(current page text area.east)-(pic cs:x\theschritte)$)
    in \pgfextra{\xdef\remainder{\x1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{varwidth}[c]{\remainder}\vspace*{0pt}{\small {#1}}\end{varwidth} \nonumber\\}%
\newcommand{\schritt}[1]{\schritttext{\ensuremath{{#1}}}}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f(x)&\tikzmarknode{eq\theschritte}{=}x^2-3x+2\\
    \schritttext{Insert a "zero" }
        &\tikzmarknode{eq\theschritte}{=} \hphantom{{}-{}}x^2-2x\frac{3}{2} + \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2\nonumber\\
         &\hphantom{{}=-{}}- \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 +2\\
    \schritttext{use $a^2-2 ab+b^2=(a-b)^2$ (binomial formula)\\ also:  $2-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2= 2- \frac{9}{4}=\frac{8-9}{4}=-\frac{1}{4}$}
    &\tikzmarknode{eq\theschritte}{=}\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X-1)}] in {1,...,\theschritte}
    \fill[decorate,decoration={footprints,foot of=gnome,
    stride length=12pt,foot sep=0pt}] (eq\Y) -- (eq\X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also use wavy lines if you are not absolutely sure about a given step. ;-)